# Why is $\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_n$ being positive on maximally entangled states sufficient to know that $\Phi$ is CP?

Tags: quantum-operation

***(Notation)*** Let $\Phi$ be a generic quantum map sending states in $\mathbb{C}^n$ into states in $\mathbb{C}^m$. We say that $\Phi$ is *positive* when $\Phi(X)\ge0$ for any positive linear operator $X\in\mathrm{Lin}(\mathbb{C}^n)$.
We say that $\Phi$ is *completely positive* (CP) when $\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_k$ is a positive map for all $k\ge0$.

***(A standard approach to proving that CP $\iff$ $n$-positive)*** It is well-known that $\Phi$ is CP *iff* its Choi representation,
$$J(\Phi)\equiv (\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_n)(|m\rangle\!\langle m|)\in\operatorname{Lin}(\mathbb{C}^m\otimes \mathbb{C}^n),$$
is positive semidefinite. Here $|m\rangle\equiv \sum_{i=1}^n |i,i\rangle$ is the (unnormalised) maximally entangled state.
A standard way to show this is to observe that

1. If $J(\Phi)$ is positive semidefinite then it admits an eigendecomposition $J(\Phi)=\sum_a v_a v_a^\dagger$ for some collection of vectors $v_a\in\mathbb{C}^m\otimes \mathbb{C}^n$;
2. The eigendecomposition for $J(\Phi)$ corresponds to a Kraus-like decomposition for $\Phi$ itself: $\Phi(X)=\sum_a A_a X A_a^\dagger$ with $A_a$ being the linear operators with the same components as the vectors $v_a$.
3. Such a Kraus-like decomposition can always be rewritten as a Stinespring-like representation $\Phi(X)=\operatorname{Tr}_1(VXV^\dagger)$ with $V\equiv \sum_a |a\rangle\otimes A_a$, and any map with such a representation is CP, because
   $$(\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_k)(\mathbb{P}(|\Psi\rangle)) = \operatorname{Tr}_1\!\!\big[\mathbb{P}((V\otimes I_k)|\Psi\rangle)\big], \qquad \mathbb{P}(|\psi\rangle)\equiv |\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|, \qquad \forall|\Psi\rangle\in \mathbb{C}^{n+k},$$
   meaning the action of any finite extension of $\Phi$ on unit-rank projections returns the partial trace of a unit-rank projection, which is always a positive semidefinite operator.

***(The question)*** Now, suppose I'm interested in proving the fact that $\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_n$ sending maximally entangled states to valid states is sufficient to know that any extension of $\Phi$ sends physical states into physical states (*i.e.* that $\Phi$ is CP). The above approach does of course work, but it involves quite a bit of machinery to show something that on the face of it seems a rather simple statement.

Is there a simpler or more direct way to show that $(\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_n)(|m\rangle\!\langle m|)$ being positive is sufficient to know that $\Phi\otimes \operatorname{Id}_k$ is a positive map for all $k$?

Comment: This is not particularly complicated (and indeed you seem to be done after 2 as you get the Kraus operators, what's the point of 3?) This seems primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch well, sure, the third point is not crucial, I probably use it because I prefer to think of maps via Stinespring. But the main rational of the question was to avoid having to pass by the eigendecomposition of the Choi altogether. Or at least, a more direct way to relate positivity on general states to the positivity on the maximally entangled state, that doesn't involve having to discuss different representations of the map etc

Comment: I agree that the full Choi proof is quite complicated; indeed, 1 and 2 together don't prove at all that the channel you get is the channel you started with (nor does 3 prove it?), so the full proof would likely be longer. (At least, when I prove the full Choi isomorphism this is taking a while.) -- I posted an argument which might well be considered easier - all you need to know is Schmidt decompositions, I believe.

Comment: ... I still don't get at all what 3 is about. I mean, it is clear that a map in Kraus form is CP, is it? (What does Kraus-"like" even mean? This is entirely a Kraus form, isn't it?)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes I agree that 2 and 3 here are essentially equivalent. Both ultimately rely on the fact that $APA$ is positive if $P$ is. The reason I said "Kraus-like" is because I was not technically working with channels, i.e. $\Phi$ could be not trace-preserving, and then the decomposition is not strictly speaking a "Kraus decomposition" I think? i.e. the "Kraus operators" do not need to satisfy the normalisation $\sum_a A_a^\dagger A_a=I$. I'm not sure whether people would talk about a proper Kraus decomposition in this case

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I'm not sure what you mean regarding 1 and 2 together not proving  that "the channel you get is the one you started with". The Kraus decomposition for $\Phi$ is completely equivalent to the eigendecomposition for $J(\Phi)$, when $v_a$ and $A_a$ are related as mentioned in the post, and such decomposition characterises the action of $\Phi$ itself. In what sense could you end up with a different channel with this procedure?

Comment: Of course you end up with the same channel, that's the point of the isomorphism. But to prove it you have to show that this is indeed the inverse map. This is quite a bit more work. Where would the proof be in your argument? Or are you allowed to *use* the isomorphism? Then I don't see what's complicated about the argument why n-positivity is enough.

Comment: Regarding "Kraus representation": The conditions for CP and TP are entirely separate. I would consider this clear, and an important point. I would call this a Kraus representation indep. of TP.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't necessarily think it's complicated, no. The equivalence of $J(\Phi)=\sum_a v_a v_a^\dagger$ and $\Phi(X)=\sum_a A_a XA_a^\dagger$ is immedate  eg looking at their components expressions and t the relation $J(\Phi)_{12,34}=\langle E_{13},\Phi(E_{24})\rangle$. Still, there might be methods that are more direct and use a different approach. Like the one you showed. But honestly, simplicity aside, I find it generally good to have different ways of proving the same results

Comment: I still feel you are sweeping quite a bit of difficulty under the rug, e.g. by the relation you quote above (or something else.) (The alterative is that the way I prove Choi in my course is faaar to complicated ;) ). I agree it is all straightforward, but actually working it out is quite tedious. If not, I would be really interested in understanding it, precisely for the reason above.

Comment: Regarding "having different ways of proving results": I fully agree. Though in the way currently asked the question probably falls under "opinion-based" by SE interpretation. Probably asking for *alternative* proofs would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch so, about the title, I kinda agree. But the reason I didn't word it like that  is that it would make a long title even longer, for no significant advantage. I figure someone looking for this kind of information would naturally land on a question with the current title anyway, and probably find what they are looking for. So I see no disadvantage in the current phrasing, even though technically speaking the title is not entirely accurate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative argument would be as follows:

1. If there exists a $\rho\ge0$ such that $\Phi\otimes \mathrm{Id}_k(\rho)\not\ge0$, then there will also exist a pure $\vert\chi\rangle$ such that $\Phi\otimes \mathrm{Id}_k(\vert\chi\rangle\langle\chi\vert)\not\ge0$. (This follows immediately from convexity, e.g. by taking an ensemble decomposition of said $\rho$ -- it will contain one such $\vert\chi\rangle$.)
2. Take the Schmidt decomposition of $\vert\chi\rangle$, and denote its Schmidt rank by $\ell$. Clearly, $\ell\le n$. Then, when considering $\Phi\otimes \mathrm{Id}_k(\vert\chi\rangle\langle\chi\vert)$, the extending space (the one with the $\mathrm{Id}$) can be compressed to a space with dimension $\ell$ (spanned by the Schmidt vectors). Call the compressed state $\vert\chi'\rangle$.
3. Clearly, in the compressed space $\Phi\otimes Id_\ell(\vert\chi'\rangle\langle\chi'\vert)\not\ge0$.

This shows that $n$-positive implies $k$-positive for $k>n$. If, in addition, you want to make sure that $n$-positivity when applied only to the maximally entangled state $\vert\Omega\rangle$ is sufficient, then you can do the following:

4. Assume wlog $\ell = n$. (Otherwise, embed into an $n$-dimensional space.) Write $\vert\chi'\rangle = (\mathrm{I}\otimes M)\vert\Omega\rangle$.
   Then,
   $$
   (\mathrm{I}\otimes M)\,\big[(\Phi\otimes \mathrm{Id}_n)(\vert\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega\vert)\big]\,(\mathrm{I}\otimes M^\dagger) = 
   (\Phi\otimes \mathrm{Id}_n)(\vert\chi'\rangle\langle\chi'\vert)
   \not\ge 0\ ,
   $$
   which proves that $(\Phi\otimes \mathrm{Id}_n)(\vert\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega\vert)\ge0$ implies $n$-positivity.

(Fun fact on the side: This argument can also be used to show that in order to check CP, it is sufficient to evaluate the action of the channel on *any* $\vert\chi'\rangle$ with maximal Schmidt rank, since in that case, $M$ is invertible, and the argument works both ways.)

Comment: ah, nice, this is the kind of thing I was hoping for. One could also make a trivial modification to the argument to make it "positive" I think: $$(\Phi\otimes\operatorname{Id}_k)(|\chi\rangle\!\langle\chi|)=(I\otimes D)[(\Phi\otimes\operatorname{Id}_n)(|\Omega\rangle\!\langle\Omega|)](I\otimes D)$$ with $D$ diagonal matrix with the Schmidt coefficients of $\chi$, so that we get a direct relation between positivity on  $|\Omega\rangle$ and positivity on arbitrary (pure) states

Comment: If D is singular this is a one-way relation. But isn't this precisely my point 4?

Comment: sure. I just like this equation because it gives a direct explicit relation answering the question: "how does the action of $\Phi\otimes\operatorname{Id}_k$ on a generic state $|\chi\rangle$ relate to the action on maximally entangled states?". It's essentially your point 4, yes, observing that the matrix $D$ is just the diagonal matrix whose elements are the Schmidt coefficients

Comment: @gls ... or my 4 using the SVD of M :)  In fact, this is one of the advanced questions I like asking in oral exams, if everything goes smoothly ;)  (Will have to remember to delete this comment! :-o)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Actually something that always bugs me is whether this theorem implies 2-positivity is enough to prove CP, since your proof essentially says that if it's 2-positive then it's true for $k > 2$. I have never seen this connection stated clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip point 3 since $\Phi(X) = AXA^\dagger$ is a CP map and a sum of CP maps is again CP. The map $\Phi$ is CP because $(\Phi \otimes {\rm Id})(Z)= (A\otimes I)Z(A\otimes I)^\dagger$ – clearly a positive map.